# Como pegar 2 casas decimais

Tags: javascript, script

Como faço para mostra apenas 2 casas decimais depois da vírgula.

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
 <script>
    function DescontoPorcentagem() {
        var bruto = $("#tot_bruto").val();
        var porcentagem = $("#Tot_desc_prc").val();
        var real = $("#Tot_desc_vlr").val();
        var total;
        total = parseFloat((parseFloat(porcentagem) / 100) * parseFloat(bruto));

        $("#Tot_desc_vlr").val(parseFloat(total));
        total = parseFloat(bruto) - parseFloat(total);
        $("#tot_liquido").val(parseFloat(total));
    }

    function DescontoReal() {
        var bruto = $("#tot_bruto").val();
        var porcentagem = $("#Tot_desc_prc").val();
        var real = $("#Tot_desc_vlr").val();
        var total;
        total = parseFloat(bruto) - parseFloat(real)
        $("#tot_liquido").val(parseFloat(total));
        total = (real / bruto) * 100
        $("#Tot_desc_prc").val(total);
    }
</script>
```

Se eu ter um valor no campo "`tot_bruto`" de 100, e der um desconto de "`00,23`"R$ ele mostra o valor da porcentagem de "0,22999999999999998"% ou se eu informa um desconto em porcentagem de "`03,4`"% ele me mostra o desconto em real de "`3,4000000000000004`"R$, eu só quero que apareça 2 casas decimais depois da vírgula.

Comment: Tenta com `.toFixed(2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com `toFixed(n)` você converte um número em string com `n` casas decimais.

```
var numero = 0.2333333;
numero.toFixed(2); // 2 casas decimais
```

**Resultado:** 0.23

O JS trabalha com casas decimais separadas por ponto ".". Se você quer o resultado com vírgula, então precisa fazer um replace no ponto:

```
numero.toFixed(2).replace(".",",");
```

**Resultado:** 0,23

> Se você já tem um número no formato "0,23333", é preciso convertê-lo
>   antes para "0.23333" para que o toFixed() funcione.

```
valor = "0,2333333"; //string que representa o número
valor = valor.replace(",","."); //troco a vírgula por ponto
valor = parseFloat(valor); // converto em número
console.log(valor.toFixed(2).replace(".",",")); // converto em string de novo, com vírgula e 2 casas decimais
```

> Para o JS, a vírgula em um número representa separação de milhar, e
>   não de casa decimal. Portanto, um número 0,23333 deve ser tratado como tipo *string*, e não como tipo *número*.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo !!

Answer (score 1):

Para que fique duas casas decimais você precisa de apenas colocar `.toFixed(2)` depois do valor recebido.